# Positioning error menu css position: relative in IE7

Tags: css, xhtml, position, internet-explorer-7

I'm with a positioning problem in IE7
have the following in my css menu

In Chrome and Firefox works correctly, but in IE7, the menu is vertical. How can I fix this?

[Page with this problem](http://infantile.montepage.com.br)

Please look at the source of the page the link up between the lines:

the menu is between the lines:

457 and 614

tag starts in:

```
<div class="colorido" style="z-index: 10000; position: relative;">
```

The area of ​​the div 'colorido' will **Destaques** to **Fale Conosco**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a fixed width to the menu's UL element.  I experimented and 550px seems spot on.

```
.colorido UL.mega-menu {
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    width: 550px;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, your code was necessary and the list is positioned correctly. Thank you.